# My model's predictions got worse from a custom loss function

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, loss-function

I am solving a regression problem for determining employee salaries. The standard objective in xgboost is MSE. MSE is not suitable for my task, so I chose another function (MAPE):

```
 abs(predict_y - true_y) / predict_y.
```

Logically, my function should improve predictions, since the salary needs a relative loss function.

My custom function:

```
def custom_loss_gradient(a, b):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        x = a[i]
        y = b[i]
        ch_t = ( ((x**2 - x*y)/(2*sqrt(abs(x-y)) *abs(x - y))) - sqrt(abs(x - y))  )
        zn_t = x**2
        t = ch_t / zn_t
        tmp.append(t)
    return np.array(tmp)

def custom_loss_hessian(a, b):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        x = a[i]
        y = b[i]
        сh_t = -3*x**3 + 5*x**2*y - 2*x*y**2 - 2*(x-y) * (-3*x + 4*y) * abs(x - y)
        zn_t = 4*x**3 * sqrt(abs(x - y)) * (x-y) * abs(x - y)
        t = сh_t / zn_t
        tmp.append(t)
    return np.array(tmp)

def finally_loss(train_yy, predt):
    predt.get_label()[predt.get_label() < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    predt = predt.get_label()
    grad = custom_loss_gradient(predt, train_yy)
    hess = custom_loss_hessian(predt, train_yy)
    return grad, hess
```

My model:

```
model = xgb.train({'tree_method':'hist', 'max_depth': 10, 'subsample': 0.6, 'colsample_bytree': 0.5, 'colsample_bynode': 0.5, 'colsample_bylevel': 0.8, 'tree_method': 'approx', 'sketch_eps': 0.4, 'seed': 1994}, obj=finally_loss, dtrain = dtrain)
```

But the results on new data are terrible:

```
y_true = [2, 7, 3, 1, 4]
y_predict = [1.6432, 1.6345, 1.6466, 1.6423, 1.6399]
```

When I use xgboost model with default loss (MSE) the results are much better:

```
y_true = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y_predict = [3, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

I'm a newbie. Please help me figure out why custom loss is worse

Comment: For a relative error, I think you should be dividing by `true_y` . You want to know, as a fraction of the true value, how far off is your prediction.

Comment: I tried, but the result is not better..

Comment: Did you also change your gradient and hessian to account for this change?

Comment: Yes, of course. I change gradient and hessian every time i change function.